# My SQL is not working

Tags: php, sql, database, append

I'm trying to add a value to a row in a database table that currently has other values. I want to effect only one field in the table. here's what I'm doing:

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET photo = ".$m_fname." WHERE pin = ".$_SESSION['pin'].";";
```

What's the correct way to do this?

Here's a little more:

```
  $m_fname = mysql_real_escape_string($dest_filename);
  $sql = "UPDATE users SET photo = ".$m_fname." WHERE pin = ".$_SESSION['pin'].";";
  $res = @mysql_query($sql);
  if (!$res) {
    $errors[] = "Could not run query.";
    break;
  }
```

**Before anyone else downvotes..**
I'm aware I should be using mysqli. Sorry if I offended anyone by using an old function.

Comment: what is the data type of `photo`?

Comment: `$exts = array('png','gif','bmp','jpg','jpeg','PNG','GIF','BMP','JPG','JPEG'); //allowed file extensions` @JohnWoo

Comment: i didn't need to do it in both uppercase and lower but i was desperate and troubleshooting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$m_fname = mysql_real_escape_string($dest_filename);
$sql = "UPDATE users SET photo = '{$m_fname}' WHERE pin = '{$_SESSION['pin']}';";
$res = @mysql_query($sql);
if (!$res) {
  $errors[] = "Could not run query.";
  break;
}
```

Comment: @Gordie : lier lier bum on fire :P :D

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this helps, it's a different implementation and it includes a proper way of data-sanitation:

```
$dbSession = new PDO('mysql:host=***;dbname=***', '***', '***');

$updateQuery = $dbSession->prepare('
  UPDATE
    `users`
  SET
    `photo` = :photo
  WHERE
    `pin` = :pin');

$updateQuery->bindParam(':photo', $m_fname,         PDO::PARAM_STR);
$updateQuery->bindParam(':pin',   $_SESSION['pin'], PDO::PARAM_INT); // or 'PARAM_STR'
$updateQuery->execute();
```

See documentation for more functions available:

- [PHP Database Objects](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are setting the field `photo` to a string value, consider using single qutation

```
$sql = "
  UPDATE `users`
  SET `photo` = '" . $m_fname . "'
  WHERE `pin` = " . $_SESSION['pin']; // Not clear what pin is (string or int)
```

What is the problem that you are facing? the code seems to be fine, provided that the `PIN` field is the primary unique key, and that `photo` is a varchar

Comment: @Cyrille Out of curiosity, why are singles better for strings? And yes, pin is primary key and photo is varchar. I don't know why it wasn't working.

Answer (score 1):

use "'" for non number

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET photo = '".$m_fname."' WHERE pin = '".$_SESSION['pin']."';";
```